# Is this sequence periodic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursive-algorithms

Suppose we have a sequence of numbers, $$t_n$$

Such that $$t_{2n} = t_n$$

and

$$t_{2n+1} = 1 - t_n$$

Also, $$t_0 = 1$$

**Is this sequence periodic?**

I have found that the sequence of numbers comprise just of 1’s and 0’s but I couldn’t find an exact proof to whether it is periodic or not.

Comment: What is $t_0$ ?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention, It is equal to 1

Comment: Your sequence has been studied. It is the Thue sequence, and is in online encyclopedia of integer sequences, https://oeis.org/A010060

Comment: I was reading more in the oeis.org/A010060 entry about your sequence, and it is known to be "cube free", meaning it does not have three identical consecutive blocks of some length anywhere in it. IF your sequence were periodic of course, it would have beyond some point all repeating blocks of some fixed length. So no, it is not periodic.

Comment: I just noticed that your sequence starts with $t_0=1.$ The official Thue sequence listed in oeis which I linked to before begins instead with $t_0=0,$ and is entry for entry the complement of yur sequence, i.e. has 0 where yours is 1 and 1 wherre yours is 0. it has the exact same recursive rules as yours for $t_{2n}$ and $t_{2n+1}.$ Thus your sequence also is cube free (and not periodic).